# JsonObject from PHP to Android + security

Tags: php, android, security, json

Hi everyone I have this php output.

```
//fetching all the rows from the query
$row = $stmt->fetchAll();
//output to json
die(json_encode($row));

[{"u_id":"8","id":"8","name":"test1","location_long":"10.01475","location_lati":"53.57823","description":"loo\nlol","date":"2014-11-21","time":"18:00:00","date_created":"2014-11-20","date_updated":"0000-00-00"},
{"u_id":"8","id":"9","name":"test9","location_long":"10.01475","location_lati":"53.57823","description":"test9\n","date":"2014-11-21","time":"19:00:00","date_created":"2014-11-20","date_updated":"0000-00-00"}, 
{"u_id":"8","id":"10","name":"test10","location_long":"10.01475","location_lati":"53.57823","description":"lol","date":"2014-11-22","time":"19:00:00","date_created":"2014-11-20","date_updated":"0000-00-00"},
{"u_id":"8","id":"11","name":"lol","location_long":"10.01475","location_lati":"53.57823","description":"","date":"2014-11-24","time":"18:00:00","date_created":"2014-11-20","date_updated":"0000-00-00"}]
```

Now I want get each item with its value into my listview item
Code:

```
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    EVENTS_URL, "POST", params);

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length();i++)
{

adapter.add(new DataProvider(own_event,
                             jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"),
                             jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"),
                             jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("date"),
                             jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("time"),
                             jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("location_long"),
                             jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("location_lati"),
                             jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id")));
 }
```

Now I get this error:

> Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value [] of type
>   org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

In the line where I create the JSONArray jsonArray.

I never worked with json before so, is there a better way to parse the data from my php file to android, and a more secure way in doing that?

Comment: Try to make JsonArray and return it from makeHttpRequest instead JsonObject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Server response is came in JSONArray so no need to convert in JSONObject just build JSONArray from server response and return as JSONArray instead JSONObject from makeHttpRequest :

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(EVENTS_URL, "POST", params);
```

Comment: That does work, but is there a more secure way? If someone hacks parameters and changes the user_id to what ever id he wants?

Comment: @Konter,For this you have to implement some encryption-decryption mechanism.

Comment: @HareshChhelana can you help me with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27393384/how-to-send-data-from-android-to-php-server-using-json?noredirect=1#comment43233981_27393384